# Rails - Check if the active record is not empty and then call relation on it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am fetching data from database using the following statement

```
@applications = Job.find(params[:job_id]).job_applications
```

Using the relationships I have setup if I do

```
@applications.first.job
```

This will give me the job, application is linked with.

Inside the view I have the following code, this fails if the `@applications` is empty.

```
  <% if !@applications.first.job.procedure %>
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
      <p>No procedure has been assigned to this job.</p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

How can I update the above if statement so it only runs if the `@applications` is not empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check whether association is present or not..

```
<% if @applications.blank? || @applications.first.job.try(:procedure).blank? %>
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <p>No procedure has been assigned to this job.</p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

OR a one liner, a little ugly though

```
@applications.try(:first).try(:job).try(:procedure).blank?
```

Comment: many thanks, i was looking for a one liner rather than adding 2 if statements

Comment: Keep in mind that try is not terribly performant, especially when it's being used to chain through associations instead of just methods on objects. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655032/try-vs-performance

Comment: Ahaa..thanx for that insight...amazed to know it's almost 3 times.